# Include in list if not None

Tags: python-3.x

Given

```
l=[]
```

I want to the value returned from function `getElem()` to `l` if the result is not `None`, what is the elegant way to do it?

One possible way

```
a=getElem()
if a!=None:
  l.append(a)
```

But I hope to have a more elegant one line solution

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an elegant way, but you aren't showing [nearly enough context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: that's the normal way to do it in python. Python lets you filter iterators and you can see some fancy one-liners for those. But this isn't an iteration. You just have a decision on whether to call append. You could `l.extend(a for a in [getElem] if a)` but that goes through a second list and is more complicated.

Comment: Your code has the advantage that it's readable and you'll be able to understand it if you come back a year from now. I think you'll find that some of the fancy one liner solutions start to get a little involved. Finally, usually **is not None** is used for comparison to None.

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished using list concatenation. You can also make this into a function if this is behavior you will use multiple times.

```
concat_if_not_none = lambda l,e: l if e is None else l + [ e ]

empty_list = [ ]
element = get_elem() 
maybe_empty_list = concat_if_not_none(empty_list, element)
```